# iphone database problem

Tags: iphone, database, xcode, sqlite

Iam making a tab-based application where in first tab i have a custom button.
and in second tab i have a table view which loading database from sqlite.

in that custom button selector i have called viewlo. whose body is like this:

info *viewer=[[info alloc]init];
 [[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewer animated:YES];
 [viewer release];

the problem is that when i click the button the database didn't appear, and shows empty table.
but when i go back and again click button it load the data. what is the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok just got it...

i just change the view did load method of info and its working now....

i just call these lines in my info viewload:

FootPainAppDelegate *appDelegate = (FootPainAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    [appDelegate getcategories];